# не прорисовываются все колонки datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

При разворачивании формы на весь экран не прорисовываются все колонки  datagridview. Какой-то баг? или в свойствах что то не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас колонки слишком широкие или что Вы имеете в виду? Немного не пойму вопрос.

Comment: см. фото. с право на фото серая полоса

Answer (score 1):

Если колонки в DataDridView слишком широкие, то советую Вам задавать их ширину при создании, так у Вас все будет помещаться как нужно, задав заранее ширину:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

Вот описание на MSDN:

[Свойство DataGridViewColumn.Width](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: это не помогает, при изменении ширины колонок, серая полоса с право (см. фото) всё равно остаётся!!

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, слева - это то что пусто?

Comment: прошу прощения, с право

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, странно, но дата в первом столбце отображается нормально, а в последнем какая-то кракозябра получается. Попробуйте очистить проект и построить заново, а также задать формат даты для последней колонки

Comment: нет, похоже у datagridview есть лимит по размерам

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, а сколько всего колонок в Вашей таблице?

Comment: я имею ввиду лимит по размерам, а не по количеству колонок

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, Возможно, но для начала необходимо поискать на просторах интернета ответ. Думаю, что проблема может быть в другом.

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, а у Вас нет возможности проверить данный пример в другой версии IDE? У вас какая версия?

Comment: @VladimirTsybin, попробуй зайти в свойства DataGridView, найди там секцию `Frozen` и установи в нем значение `False`.